# Lodash: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, lodash

I'm following pluralsight - Building mobile app with ionic.

but this code keep showing TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

if i commented out vm.teamName = team.name; it works but wouldn't show the team name. Here's the code

```
var team = _.chain(data.teams)
                    .flatten("divisionTeams")
                    .find({ "id": vm.teamId })
                    .value();

        vm.teamName = team.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

It clearly states the `team` is undefined. check what you get while doing a `console.log(team)` before attempting to access a property from the `object`.

```
var team = _.chain(data.teams)
                    .flatten("divisionTeams")
                    .find({ "id": vm.teamId })
                    .value();

vm.teamName = team.name;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

```
var divisionTeams = _.map(data.teams, function(team) {
  return team.divisionTeams;
});

var team = _.find(_.flatten(divisionTeams), {id: 1});
```

`_.flatten` doesn't take that kind of argument. See the [docs](https://lodash.com/docs)

Here is a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/trollr/22sowjhj/

Comment: console.log(flattenTeams); returns empty array

Comment: Not for me. It's a working fiddle. You changed anything? See: https://picload.org/image/rgrrlwlp/flatten.jpg